# Ajax call to Flask Rest API does not get JSON

Tags: json, ajax, flask

I have the following ajax call to my REST API with Flask:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/addEvent",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "event_id": "e-123"
        }),
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";        
        if ( xhr.status == 200 ) {
            console.log("Event created.");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error! status: " + xhr.status)
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, exception) {
        console.log("error > xhr.status:" + xhr.status);
        console.log("error > exception: " + exception);
    },
    complete: function(response, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Finished!");
    }
});
```

My Flask REST API app.py file contains this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
def addEvent():
    request_data = request.get_json()
```

However, 'request_data' is `None` while `request.get_data()` contains `b'{"event_id":"e-123"}'`

Did I make something wrong in my ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a string to your Flask REST API.

Try changing your data field in ajax call from:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "event_id": "e-123"
    })
```

to

```
data: {
    "event_id": "e-123"
    }
```

Comment: This does not change anything. 
request.get_json()  is still None while request.get_data() contains b'event_id=e-123'

Answer (score 1):

Add `contentType: 'application/json'` on your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/addEvent",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: ...
```